# SP 2016 Workflows - Access Denied on Current List

Tags: workflow, permissions, sharepoint-addin, app-step

In SharePoint 2016, I have created a workflow to run on creation. If fields in the item match certain criteria, the item should have a field updated with a specified value.

[image]

I receive the following error using my test account that has Contribute permissions on the list.
[image]

The guid `8e944724-18a2-4e12-8610-6f159acf7d96` matches the guid of the list the workflow runs on.

**Why is my test account (and other accounts with the same permssions) receiving this error if I have Contribute rights?**

I can access the list's properties through the REST API endpoint mentioned in the error.

I also attempted to run the same workflow with an App Step and gave the Workflow add in Full Control. This still did not allow me or other users to run the workflow and resulted in the same error.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

[image]

**How can this be corrected?**

Answer (score 1):

A couple of immediate thoughts on this.

1 -> Try this link and steps -> https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/

2 -> I have seen an Anomaly before where in the Workflow Settings page, there is a setting to allow the workflow to update the status. I have seen this Unauthorized happen because of this box before..... Similar to this screenshot... Uncheck the box and try it again.

[image]

**BEST OF LUCK TO YOU, LET US KNOW!**